# Angular 8 using ngIf with async pipe to show and hide the HTML element

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, observable

I am trying to show and hide HTML elements according to the service result. I am using `*ngIf="messageService.getData() | async"` but it isn't working to show or hide the element. I am using async, otherwise "Failure Message" is shown for a short time and then "Successful Message" is shown.

I have 2 tags like these:

```
<div *ngIf="messageService.getData() | async">Successful Message</div>
<div *ngIf="!messageService.getData() | async">Failure Message</div>
```

In the service I have a code like this:

```
export class MessageService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  public getData() {
    return this.http.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1")
    .pipe(
      map((response) => {
        console.log("success");
      }),
      catchError(this.handleError)
    )
  }

  private handleError(error: Response) {
    console.log("handleError")
    let errMsg: string;
    errMsg = "error"
    return Observable.throw(errMsg);
  }
}
```

Here is the source code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-iqr6az

Answer (score 7, accepted):

in your service:

```
public getData() {
    return this.http.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1")
    .pipe(
      map((response) => {
        return response; // return res
      }),
      catchError(this.handleError)
    )
  }
```

in your component:

```
export class MessageComponent implements OnInit {
  isServiceAPIWorking: boolean;
  todos;
  loadingError$ = new Subject<boolean>();
  constructor(private messageService: MessageService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.todos = this.messageService.getData().pipe(
      catchError((error) => {
        // it's important that we log an error here.
        // Otherwise you won't see an error in the console.
        console.error('error loading the list of users', error);
        this.loadingError$.next(true);
        return of();
      })
    );
  }
}
```

in your html:

```
<div>Show Message:</div>
<div *ngIf="todos | async">Successfull Message</div>
<div *ngIf="loadingError$ | async">Failure Message</div>
```

[**DEMO**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nbxpyp).

Comment: well done @Fateme this is the best answer i see and also i do when i face such a problem.

Comment: @FatemeFazli I am trying to see the "Failure Message" but it is giving Observable.throw is not a function error. I changed it to "throwError" but it is still not displaying.

Answer (score 1):

Why bother with async pipes when you can just assign the data in your component?

```
// message.component.ts

class MessageComponent implements OnInit {
  isServiceAPIWorking: boolean;
  data: any;
  constructor(private messageService: MessageService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.messageService.getData()
      .subscribe(response => {
        this.isServiceAPIWorking = true;
        // Assign the data
        this.data = response;
      },
        error => {
          this.isServiceAPIWorking = false;
        })
  }
}
```

```
// message.component.html

<div>Show Message:</div>
<div *ngIf="data">Successfull Message</div>
<div *ngIf="!data">Failure Message</div>
```

And there is a mistake in your service. If you use `map` without returning anything, you won't get any data in the end. Use `tap` if you want to do logging:

```
// message.service.ts

public getData() {
  return this.http.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1")
  .pipe(
    tap((response) => {
      console.log("success");
    }),
    catchError(this.handleError)
  )
}
```

[Updated Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mv51v8)

Comment: If you don't use async, "Failure Message" is shown for a short time and then "Sucess Message" is shown.

Comment: Yeah, sure, I just adapted your logic but you can do more clever things to do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

This is a wrong usage of `async` pipe not in syntactical but in semantic way. Every time a change detection triggered, you are making an HTTP request.

Rather than checking with `async` pipe, you can store two flags (boolean variables) or one boolean variable for HTTP request and one variable for response.

Below example is using two flags.

```
export class MessageService {

  isLoaded = false;
  hasError  = false;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  public getData() {
    this.isLoaded = false;
    this.http.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1")
    .subscribe(
       (response) => {
           this.hasError = false;
           this.isLoaded = true;
       },
       (error) => {  
           this.hasError = true;
           this.isLoaded = true;
       },
    )
  }
}
```

And in the template:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="isLoaded">
    <div *ngIf="!hasError">Successfull Message</div>
    <div *ngIf="hasError">Failure Message</div>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: I see your point but if you don't use async, "Failure Message" is shown for a short time on page load.

Comment: Hmm.. Swapping the assigning of `isLoaded` and `hasError` has any effect? Updated the answer